# Declaring the value of a variable and calling it in an include later on (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement, include, echo

I'm surprised I couldn't find a similar question on this site. Maybe my search abilities are a bit rusty...

So I am naming a variable in the `<head>` of each page in my site, like this:

`<?php $color="orange" ?>`

Color could also equal blue or green or whatever. So if the color is orange, I want to display an orange inside of an include file on the site. Let's say... for the menu...

`<?php include 'inc/menu.php'; ?>`

Now, inside of that include I have something like this:

`<?php if ($color="orange") { echo "<span id='showmyorange'></span>";} else {echo "";} ?>`

I may also use something like this:

`<div class="<?php echo $color>">`

However, it seems to default to one option, as if defining the value of `$color` without looking back at the information in the header of my page, as if `$color=""`. How can I define the value of a variable outside of the include file in which it is called?

Comment: no reason that should not work. an included file acts as if it the code was on the page, the only potential problem is if your using $color in a function .. ok MAXIM is right its the "==" issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change this line:

```
<?php if ($color="orange") { echo "<span id='showmyorange'></span>";} else {echo "";} ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php if ($color=="orange") { echo "<span id='showmyorange'></span>";} else {echo "";} ?>
```

notice the double == sign. One is for assigning the variable, two "==" for confronting the values.

Comment: The cute thing here is that if ($color="orange") will return you always true, as the variable assignment *IS* successful. This leads to great confusions sometimes ;)

Comment: dammit dammit dammit. I can't believe I let that slip through my fingers. Thanks!